# SOAP Service Logger not sending data to proper file

Tags: spring, soap, log4j

Below is the snippet from my log4j.xml which sets up the logging for all Soap Service messaging.  Unfortunately I'm not seeing any of the SOAP data being logged to my logfile.  Errors are logged but the actual message request/response is not getting logged.

Am I missing something?  Based on all of the information I've read it seems to be setup properly.

```
<appender name="WS_REQUEST_LOG" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${log4j.ws-req}" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="50MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="40" />
    <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
    <layout class="common.log.PatternLayout"></layout>
</appender>

<!-- Write responses to web services received to rolling log -->
<logger name="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing" additivity="false">
    <level value='TRACE'/>
    <appender-ref ref="WS_REQUEST_LOG" />       
</logger>

<!-- Write web services received to rolling log -->
<logger name="org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing" additivity="false">
    <level value='TRACE' />
    <appender-ref ref="WS_REQUEST_LOG" />       
</logger>
```

Comment: I think you should replace the word `logger` with `appender` and double-quote the values of levels (I mean `"TRACE"` instead of `'TRACE'`)

Comment: Tried that but no luck.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Show us your appender `WS_REQUEST_LOG`

Comment: added the WS_REQUEST_LOG to my question.  Thanks.